# Edit default read more text in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to customize the read-more link on my WordPress theme, however I would like it to be able to get the attributes sent in the read more tag.

So the `<--more-->` tag would return the default

While `<--more Some Attribute -->` would return Some Attribute.

I'm aware that I can edit the read more text with what's below. I just can't figure out how to get the attributes or vars that are passed to the more short-code. If I could figure this out I could simply check if it exists and if not then place in the default text.

```
function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '<div class="read-more"><a class="more-link button" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Custom Read More Link Text</a></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.

Inside my function.php file I needed

```
function wrap_readmore($more_link) {
//Check if link contains default (more...), if it does replace with Read More
if (preg_match('(more&hellip;)', $more_link)) {
    $more_link = str_replace('(more&hellip;)', 'Read More', $more_link);
}

return '<div class="small-12 columns text-center">' . $more_link . '</div>';
}

add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'wrap_readmore');
```

Answer (score 0):

what customization you are trying to do ?  what about changing the class or using that class use jquery and customize the div !!!

WordPress makes this technique easy, and customizable.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Comment: I changed my question to show what I mean. I didn't realize it wasn't escaping the comment tags and not showing up.